# How to autowire a bean when a new instance of class is created using new keyword

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a new instance of a component using the **new** keyword. The component class has an auto wiring of another class. In the First class, it has a method which calls the of the second class.
The code is as follows:

**First.java**

```
@Component
public class First {
    @Autowired
    private Second second;

    public First() {
        System.out.println("This is the first class constructor.");
    }

    public void printFromFirst() {
        second.printFromSecond();
    }
}
```

**Second.java**

```
@Component
public class Second {
    public void printFromSecond() {
        System.out.println("This is inside the second class print method.");
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public First first() {
        First first = new First();
        first.printFromFirst();
        return first;
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'first' defined in com.example.sample.SampleApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.sample.First]: Factory method 'first' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.sample.Second.printFromSecond()" because "this.second" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.example.sample.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.sample.First]: Factory method 'first' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.sample.Second.printFromSecond()" because "this.second" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.sample.Second.printFromSecond()" because "this.second" is null
    at com.example.sample.First.printFromFirst(First.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.sample.SampleApplication.first(SampleApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.sample.SampleApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$badcf278.CGLIB$first$0() ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.sample.SampleApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$badcf278$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$68c83451.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.example.sample.SampleApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$badcf278.first() ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I am able to workout the solution using the dependency injection. I just want to do it this way.

TIA

Comment: Someone needs to set `this.second` into a `First` instance. If you pass through Spring, they will do it for you. If you don't (meaning using `new First()`), then you have to do it. But there is no such magic like "you use `new First()` without passing through dependency injection and you still have the dependency injected somehow.

Comment: Thank you @MatteoNNZ for the reply. And yeah, it is kind of my requirement. Is there any kind of workaround for this?

Comment: What is the requirement exactly? That people can do `new First()` and Java understands that it needs to inject a `new Second()` from somewhere? No, that's impossible, the JVM can't guess it anyhow.

Comment: To be more precise, Spring works like this (very high level). You annotate your elements, on class Second you put a Component annotation, on class First you add an Autowire for the field Second. When the Spring application starts, it will scan all the classes and collect all the beans. When it is requested to create First, it sees that a field of type Second needs to be autowired. Hence, it builds one Second and sets it into the instance of First. As I said before, it's not magic but simply done by them. If you want to use "new" (pure Java instancing), you have no choice but do the same.

Comment: prototype scope is basically a "new" every time you call a bean, since you are using Spring, why just not make First bean of the scope prototype?

Answer (score -1):

While this is a nasty hack, and I don't think anyone would recommend doing anything like this, this should "work" (it will introduce many problems):

```
@Component
public class First {

    private static First instance;

    @Autowired
    private Second second;
    
    public First() {
        if (instance != null) {
            this.second = instance.second;
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        instance = this;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a hack, it's simply wrong. You don't create a new instance of first, you always reuse the same instance

Comment: It is a new instance of First @MatteoNNZ, using the same dependancy as the first instance. I don't think this is worth anything, but it is possible.